# How to write a Polyline in GoLang

Tags: go, polyline

I want to print a "Polyline()" function in go lang with the set of coordinates:

```
x      y
300  250
400  350
250  600
```

I don't understand this structure:

```
Polyline(x []int, y []int, s ...string)
```

Please show how to carry about that polyline in GoLang

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [package svg](https://godoc.org/github.com/ajstarks/svgo)
>
> import "github.com/ajstarks/svgo"
>
> Package svg generates SVG as defined by the Scalable Vector Graphics
>   1.1 Specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/). Output goes to the specified io.Writer.
>
> [func (*SVG) Polyline](https://godoc.org/github.com/ajstarks/svgo#SVG.Polyline)
>
> ```
> func (svg *SVG) Polyline(x []int, y []int, s ...string)
> ```
>
> Polyline draws connected lines between coordinates, with optional
>   style. Standard Reference:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#PolylineElement

For example,

```
x := []int{300, 400, 250}
y := []int{250, 350, 600}
s := []string{`fill="none"`}
canvas.Polyline(x, y, s...)
```